# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

**If i don't have records in my database table, i am getting an error Invalid argument supplied foreach() can you help me out from this error.**

**controller code**

```
$data['cc'] = $this->Profile_model->supplier_companydetails();
$this->load->view('suppliercompany', $data);
```

**Model code**

```
public function supplier_companydetails() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('supplier_otherdetails');
        $this->db->where('supplierid_fk', $this->session->id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        //return $query->result();

           if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                //add all data to session
                $newdataaa = array(

                     'company_name' => $row->company_name,
                     'company_estd_date' => $row->company_estd_date,
                     'tin_number' => $row->tin_number,
                     'company_address' => $row->company_address,
                     'area' => $row->area,
                     'city' => $row->city,
                     'state' => $row->state,
                     'country' => $row->country,

                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdataaa);
            return $query->result();
        }

    }
```

Comment: if ($query->num_rows() > 1) { ... this if statement should end at return $query->result(); and 1 else condition else{ return $error='Not record found'}

Comment: are you understand what i say?

Comment: I have tried your code. Even though form is not getting open in view page

Comment: load view with $error or $result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify this line

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
```

**To**

> foreach ((array)$query->result() as $row) {

Comment: this my for each  foreach ($cc as $row) { } just edit and show me

Comment: `foreach ((array)$cc as $row) { }`

Comment: same i tried but in view page not showing anything empty page will displaying

Comment: Yes, But your question is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` i think now it has resolved.  But Now your data showing empty it means you have to look into your data set... as per my finding change this line `$this->db->where('supplierid_fk', $this->session->id);` To `$this->db->where('supplierid_fk=', $this->session->id);`  and also check `$this->session->id` something returning or not.