# no record found in database like that error showing Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and view page not display

Tags: php, codeigniter

[if records does not exist in database like that form i want to display but empty form displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLS3q.png)

**Model code**

- No record found in database, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
  like that error display and in view page form will not display if
  data found in database it will display please help me

  public function buyer_details() {

  ```
          $this->db->select('*');
          $this->db->from('customer_otherdetails');
          $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->id);
          $query = $this->db->get();
        //  return $query->result();
          if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
              foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                  //add all data to session
                  $newdataa = array(

                      'address' => $row->address,
                       'pincode' => $row->pincode,
                       'city' => $row->city,
                       'district' => $row->district,
                       'state' => $row->state,
                      'country' => $row->country,

                  );
              }
              $this->session->set_userdata($newdataa);
              return $query->result();
          }
      }
  ```

**controller code**

```
$data['buyerdetails'] = $this->Profile_model->buyer_details();
        $this->load->view('buyerdetails', $data);
```

**view page**

```
<?php
        foreach ($buyerdetails as $row) {
            ?>
<li class="has-sub">
                                            <span>Area</span>
                                            <span><?php echo $row->address; ?></span>
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefive">

                                                <?php
                                                if (empty($buyerdetails) == $this->session->userdata('address')) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <span class="profile-edit">Add</span>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <span class="profile-edit">Edit</span>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </a>
                                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="sub">
                                            <div class="panel-body ">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">

                                                        <label style="display:inline;">Area</label> 
                                                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->customerid_fk; ?>" />
                                                        <input style="width:50%;height:20px;" type ="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->address; ?>"/></br>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 12px;"><b>Note:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
                                                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                                                        <!--                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>-->
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: see the reference - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365326/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach/43365753#43365753`  I had resolve this yesterday.

Comment: that one is different why the form is not opening in view page

Comment: Maybe I understand. If no data then show blank form. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `buyer_details` does not always return something. You need to put a return outside of the `if($query->num_rows() > 0)` condition.

```
public function buyer_details()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customer_otherdetails');
    $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $rows = $query->result(); //so you only have to call result once
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdataa = array(
              'address' => $row->address,
              'pincode' => $row->pincode,
              'city' => $row->city,
              'district' => $row->district,
              'state' => $row->state,
              'country' => $row->country,
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdataa);
        //put the return outside the if
        //return $query->result();
    }
    return $rows; //this will be an empty array if no data found
}
```

`$rows` may be an empty array if no data is found. But `foreach` won't complain about an empty array. An empty array is still a valid argument.

Comment: thanks sir your code is working but one problem in database there is no data means empty page displaying even inside form is not displaying why i dont no

Comment: plz once refer above images